# NSException with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm building my first IOS 7 iPad app in Xcode 5 - but I need some help with this issue.

I'm following [this](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/) tutorial:

I don't quite understand what the writer means with:
"So open up testPickerViewController.h and we want to add in the following to the class reference."

```
UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

I got my view controller.h file here:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : ViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
IBOutlet UIImageView *customImage;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;

@end
```

my view controller.m file:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize imgPicker, customImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Init the image picker
self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
- (IBAction)AddImage:(id)sender {
// Let the user add an image for the specific subject
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
customImage.image = img;
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

I ran the app without doing what I wrote at the top, which resulted in an NSException in the main.m file.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

```
main.m

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

**Edit**

2014-05-17 14:56:47.509 myApp[1424:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'

Comment: And the exception message is ... ?

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: have you put breakpoint and checked which line is causing exception in this case?

Comment: "Terminating", yes, but it should also tell you a description of the exception.

Comment: where? I'm totally new to Xcode you see :)

Comment: Enable Zombie objects For details of crash see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint click debug continue a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post thatand an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: I've added the breakpoint. I run the app and it opens main.m straight away. Found it. 2 sec

Comment: Under the Debug Menu is "Continue".

Comment: Done that now, see my update - is that correct?

Comment: You need to one the Debug area: Under the "View" Menu, "Debug Area" then "Show Debug Area". That is where the error and backtrace is shown. Really consider a tutorial on Xcode. [Ray Wenderlich Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com) are considered to be good.

Comment: I'm in the debug area now - there are 2 windows, a split thing - what do you want me to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the connection for the `IBOutlet customImage` in Interface Builder (IB) and make sure that the name of the referencing outlet and the UIImageView match. You can check by clicking on the Connection Inspector in IB (it's a little arrow inside of a circle).

In the tutorial that you posted a link to it shows the `IBOutlet UIImageView` declared as `image`. I'm assuming you changed the name of the IBOutlet and forgot to reconnect it. You can also check if the `IBOutlet customImage` is connected by checking if the dot beside the property declaration is filled or empty. Filled = connected and Empty = not connected.

**Example of a property declaration for an IBOutlet:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * customImage;
```

Also, `<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>` are protocols. By adding those lines to the `@interface` declaration you are, very simply, stating that, "I want my `UIViewController` to conform to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. I also want to implement my own code when certain events happen."

Comment: I checked the link and it's correct. I changed my .h code slightly, see my update

Comment: I removed the image link from the ImageView and suddenly it worked

Comment: Fantastic. I'm glad everything is working for you now. Keep reading tutorials and you'll get the hang of things.

Comment: I certainly will:) Thank you for you help!